# Using list elements in a form in Django template

Tags: python, django, list, django-views, django-templates

I have the following form in a Django template. The list prize is a list of numbers defined in my view.py. Specifically, prize is defined to be

prize = [0]*total

I want to have the elements of prize listed as the default values on user input fields.

I have tried to do this with the following code.

```
<form>
{% for i in total %}
    <label for="match_{{ i }}">Enter the prize received for getting {{ i }} matches:</label>
    <input type="number" name="match_{{ i }}" id="match_{{ i }}" required value="{{ prize.i|default:'' }}">
    <br>
{% endfor %}
</form>
```

While I get no errors, I only get the empty forms with no default values. Any ideas? I have checked that the list prize is rendered correctly as I can print out their values on the webpage fine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a workaround by directly looping over prize instead and then using forloop.counter to keep the indices consistent.

```
<form>
{% for i in prize %}
    <label for="match_{{ forloop.counter }}">Enter the prize received for getting {{ forloop.counter }} matches:</label>
    {% with temp_prize=pick_ball %}
    <input type="number" name="match_{{ forloop.counter }}" id="match_{{ forloop.counter }}" required value="{{ i|default:'' }}" min="0" max="67000000">
    {% endwith %}
    <br>
{% endfor %}
</form>
```

Would still be interesed if anyone else knows any other way to do this!